# Retrieve current theme's file path instead of its name as a symbol

Tags: themes

To know which theme is active ATM one could look in `custom-enabled-themes`, which is a list containing the theme name as a symbol.

But consider the following example case. You've installed the latest version of `leuven-theme` from MELPA and now it is your current loaded theme. Since Emacs ships an older version of `leuven-theme`, which one is active, the version from MELPA or the default in Emacs?

How can you get the current theme's file path instead of just the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load-theme` does [the following](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/custom.el#L1212) to get the theme's path:

```el
(locate-file (concat (symbol-name theme) "-theme.el")
             (custom-theme--load-path)
             '("" "c"))
```

So if you just did `M-x load-theme leuven`, that'll be your path.

Comment: Neat. The list of searched directories is determined by the `custom-theme--load-path` function. Its output reveals that external themes always have precedence.